# How to add elements in custom Dictionary using C#?

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, nested, addition

I have a dictionary for clustering purpose in a class named `Cluster` in C# as:

`Dictionary<int, List<ClusterMember>>`

whereas `int` represent the *cluster id*, `List<ClusterMember>>` represent the *members* in that *cluster id* and `ClusterMember` is another class. I have shown here the whole code structure as:

```
public class ClusterMember
{
    public string _name { get; set; }
}

public class Cluster
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<ClusterMember>> _dic { get; set; }  

    public Cluster(int _id, List<ClusterMember> _clusMem)
    {
       _dic.Add(_id, _clusMem);
    }
}
```

whereas I have used these classes in this method as:

```
public static List<Cluster> DP_Cluster(List<string> _customer, double _alpha)
{
    var _currentClusters = 0; // current number of clusters i.e. "k"
    var _memberNumber = 0;    // running member number i.e. "n"
    //var _dic = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
    var _probOld = 0.0;
    var _probNew = 0.0;


    List<Cluster> _myClusters = new List<Cluster>();
    //Cluster _cluster = new Cluster(?);  
    // How to Add cluster using above classes
    // How to Add cluster Member using above classes  
    _myClusters.Add(_cluster);

    //_dic.Add(_currentClusters, _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber));
    _currentClusters += 1;

    for(int _i = 1; _i < _customer.Count - 1; _i++)
    {
        if( _i <= _currentClusters)
        {
            _probOld = myClusters[_i].Members.Count / ((_i+1) - 1 + _alpha);
        }
        else
        {
            _probNew = _alpha / ((_i+1) - 1 + _alpha);
        }

        if(_probNew > _probOld)
        {
            // Add _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber+=1) to New Cluster
            Cluster cluster = new Cluster( _currentClusters += 1 ); 
            myClusters.Add(cluster);
        }
        else
        {
            // Add _customer.ElementAt(_memberNumber+=1) to Old Cluster
        }
    }

    return myClusters;
}
```

Now how do I Add in `_dic` object of `Dictionary` while in `for loop`? Moreover I may have to add more than one *cluster members* to same `_id` more than once as

- I may add a *cluster member* to `_id = 1` in an iteration,
- then have to add a *cluster member* to an `_id = 2` in another
  iteration,
- then it may turn to add another *cluster member* to same id i.e. `_id = 1` and vice versa.

Moreover, it'll be more meaningful to me if it is possible to start *cluster id* with `1` (not `0`as of default `_dic` *index*).

Comment: can you show your `for loop` code?

Comment: I would think about removing your dictionary of clusters from the Cluster class as that should really only encapsulate an individual cluster and the functionality for it. Perhaps think about creating a ClusterDictionary class and adding in functionality in there for adding a cluster member / removing a cluster member.

Comment: @kienct89 I have shown whole `method` containing `for loop` as well

Answer (score 0):

> Moreover I may have to add more than one cluster members to same id
>   more than once

You can check for the key for each loop iteration like that:

```
public void AddInCluster(int id, List<ClusterMember> _clusMem)
{
    if (_dic.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        foreach (var clusterMember in _clusMem)
        {
            _dic[id].Add(clusterMember);                    
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _dic.Add(id, _clusMem);
    }
}
```

Or you can use the TryGetValue from Dictionary:

```
public void AddInCluster(int id, List<ClusterMember> _clusMem)
{
    List<ClusterMember> members;
    if (_dic.TryGetValue(id, out members))
    {
        foreach (var clusterMember in _clusMem)
        {
            members.Add(clusterMember);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        _dic.Add(id, _clusMem);
    }       
}
```

> Moreover, it'll be more meaningful to me if it is possible to start
>   cluster id with 1

What about wrapping your `int` into a `ClusterId` class which could raise exception if an id is 0?
Also your Cluster class could override the accessor operator [] on the dictionary to give a meaningful abstraction in your context (starting from 1 instead of 0 for example)

You may also add a `Get` working like your `Add` to check if this id exists:

```
public List<ClusterMember> GetFromCluster(ClusterId id)
{
    if (_dic.ContainsKey(id))
    {
        return _dic[id];
    }

    throw new ClusterDoesNotContainsThisId(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `Add` method for [Dictionaries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)? like:

```
if(needToAddNewCluster){
    _dic.Add(index, new List<ClusterMember>());
}
if(needToExtendCluster){
    _dic[index].Add(clusMem);
}
```

in this i assume that `needToAddNewCluster` checks that `_dic.ContainsKey(index)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add method to your Cluster class

```
public void AddToCluster(int id, ClusterMember member)
{
    // checks if cluster with specific id is already in Dictionary
    if(!_dic.ContainsKey(id))
       _dic.Add(id,new List<ClusterMember>());

     _dic[id].Add(member);
}
```

You can use it in iteration like this

```
int id = 1; // cluster id
foreach(var m in members)
{
   // adding members to cluster with id = 1
   cluster.AddToCluster(id,m);
}
```

UPDATE

*also can we get list count for each cluster id i.e. cluster members count for each cluster id?*

You can add these two methods

```
// get members count for specific cluster id
public int GetCount(int id)
{
     return _dict[id].Count;
}

// get members count for all clusters
public Dictionary<int,int> GetCounts()
{
    return _dict.ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.Value.Count);
}
```

Which you can access like this

```
var counts = cluster.GetCounts();
var c1Cnt=counts[1]; // 1 is cluster id
```

Comment: @stanke--in your method `AddtoCluster` how we extend old cluster ?

Comment: @stanke--also can we get list count for each cluster id i.e. cluster members count for each cluster id?

Comment: @maliks - extend in what way?

Comment: @stanke--extend means adding members to existing cluster---also `_dic[id].Value.Add(member);` giving error i.e. _doesn't contain a definition for Value_

Comment: @maliks - I updated methods. Extending part is already covered in first method

Comment: @stanke--thanks for update...can you please show me how to add _first element_ from `DP_Cluster` method input `List<string> _customer` to `//Cluster _cluster = new Cluster(?);` this object i.e. `_cluster`

Comment: @stanke--I tried like this:  `_cluster.AddToCluster(_currentTables += 1, _customer.ElementAt(_customerNumber));` but _invalid arguments_ error raised

Comment: @stanke--are you having a look at it please ? I need practical usage of `AddtoCluster` method in class `Cluster`...waiting for your response

Comment: @stanke--haven't you looked at it?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the implementation of the `Culster` class slightly. The `_dic` should be a getter only property with an initializer. According to the usual .NET C# naming conventions, properties should be in PascalCase, therefore I renamed it to `Dic`. (A better name would be `MemberDictionary` or `Members`). Underlined _camelCase identifiers are usually used for fields. Method parameters and local variables have camelCase.

Then add new methods for adding one or several members. Both methods first check to see whether the list is already there. If it's there new members are added to the list, otherwise a new list is created initialized with the new members and then added to the dictionary.

```
public class Cluster
{
    public Dictionary<int, List<ClusterMember>> Dic { get; }
        = new Dictionary<int, List<ClusterMember>>();

    // Initialize empty cluster.
    public Cluster()
    {
    }

    // Initialize cluster with one initial member.
    public Cluster(int key, ClusterMember member)
    {
        Add(key, member);
    }

    // Initialize cluster with many members.
    public Cluster(int key, IEnumerable<ClusterMember> members)
    {
        Add(key, members);
    }

    // Allows you to a one new member.
    public void Add(int key, ClusterMember member)
    {
        if (Dic.TryGetValue(key, out var memberList)) {
            memberList.Add(member);
        } else {
            memberList = new List<ClusterMember> { member };
            Dic.Add(key, memberList);
        }
    }

    // Allows you to add many members.
    public void Add(int key, IEnumerable<ClusterMember> members)
    {
        if (Dic.TryGetValue(key, out var memberList)) {
            memberList.AddRange(members);
        } else {
            memberList = new List<ClusterMember>(members);
            Dic.Add(key, memberList);
        }
    }
}
```

This implementation delegates the dictionary and list creation and the details of adding members to the `Cluster` class.

Btw.: Dictionaries work with a key, not an index.

---

I don't know where you are getting the member number from, nor do I understand your clustering algorithm; however, I think that with these changes `DP_Cluster` could look like this:

```
public static List<Cluster> DP_Cluster(List<string> customers, double alpha)
{
    double probOld = 0.0;
    double probNew = 0.0;

    var clusters = new List<Cluster>();
    Cluster currentCluster = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < customers.Count; i++) {
        if (i <= clusters.Count) {
            probOld = clusters[i].Dic.Count / (i + alpha);
        } else {
            probNew = alpha / (i + alpha);
        }

        if (probNew > probOld || currentCluster == null) {
            currentCluster = new Cluster();
            clusters.Add(currentCluster);
        }
        currentCluster.Add(_memberNumber, new ClusterMember { Name = customers[i] });
    }

    return clusters;
}
```

Some of the constructors and methods in `Cluster` could prove superfluous eventually, as we are always adding one single customer at a time.